# submit post request through Document Builder

Tags: java, xml, dom, servlets, document

```
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(request.getInputStream());
```

Request here  is sent as POST;
But I am unable to  get the process the request in the servlet. 
Below exception is thrown

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:98)
```

Can any one please suggest me the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this.xmlHttp.open("POST",url, this.async);
 this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
 this.xmlHttp.send(Params);

Comment: This is how i m sending a POST request to a servlet(url).

Comment: @Suki - What client library is this? What is the value of `Params`? Is `Params` XML data? `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is not an appropriate content type for an XML payload.

Comment: McDowell ,Here is my implementaion :Inside JavaScript xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); this.xmlHttp.open("POST",url, this.async);  this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  this.xmlHttp.send(Params);
In Servlet public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(request.getInputStream()) ;//Exception here.
}

Comment: Values of Params is 
Params = "sessionid=324trt"
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(request.getInputStream());
```

This Java code is for parsing XML.

```
xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
this.xmlHttp.open("POST",url, this.async);
this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
this.xmlHttp.send("sessionid=324trt");
```

This browser JavaScript code sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data. The payload `sessionid=324trt` is not XML.

The correct way to read the parameter would be [via the parameter map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29):

```
String sessionid = request.getParameter("sessionid");
```

Comment: Thanks.I Got ur point.
I am able to access the request parameters. But I need to send this request to an xmlparser for parsing
Everything works fine when I pass the parameters as query string but I do not want to do in that way since i have the requirement to restrict it.
If I restrict the URL to the servlet name :Example http:...../host/servletname and pass the parameters in the body of the request as a original POST request,i m getting the above error.

Comment: @Suki - I do not understand - there is no XML. [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) is not XML.

Comment: ok.. Forget about all the above. Now I am sending an  POST request to a servlet using AJAX CALL as above to the servlet. Inside the servlet when I do this thing Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(request.getInputStream()); I m getting the above stated error. Please give me a solution. Thanks a lot  in advance for spending ur time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Do what @McDowell suggests above and post your xml as a POST parameter. Then read the parameter in your servlet and do this --

```
String postedXml = request.getParameter("postedXml");
StringReader reader = new StringReader( postedXml );
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( reader );
Document doc = builder.parse( inputSource );
reader.close();
```